# Why do I have so many of the same rules in my Windows Firewall utility for inbound rules?

Tags: windows-firewall

I want to connect to my virtual machine using a ssh-tunnel but my program cannot bind to port 9000.

In my Windows Firewall I have many same/similar inbound rules for the same program?  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rule is probably a different rule, different port, different protocol, etc. all needed to make the connection for that server type.

Have you looked at each of the rules to see what they're doing?

In addition to that, there are often multiple versions of each rule, one for each type of network you may connect to (Public, Private or Domain; under the "Profile" column in the firewall manager).

If you think one of those rules is preventing you from using 9000, have you tried disabling the firewall completely to ensure/eliminate it as the problem?

Comment: I didn't verify every rule but I think some are redundant. I can't find a rule that is blocking my program from accessing port 9000.

Comment: @David OK, so did you try disabling the firewall to ensure it's the culprit as to why you can't connect to 9000?   Regardless, unless you can provide more specific information, my answer still stands as to why you may be seeing what you feel are redundant entries. :)

Comment: Probably blocked in the router, needs to port forward 9000

Comment: @Moab Perhaps, but that requires assuming that he's trying to connect from outside his LAN.  But regardless, this question is about "why all the dupe rules?", not "Why can't I connect to port 9000?". :)

Comment: @techie007: Just a friendliy hint: Not always it's good to find the difference. Maybe it's better to ask for the similarity?

Comment: @techie007 question is ambiguous at best. They are trying to solve a problem of a different nature.

Comment: @Moab I agree and almost flagged it a not a real question, but after rereading it a couple times it seemed that by just eliminating the one question mark made the body match the title and narrow the question down.   David may want to ask other (more specific) questions if his real goal is to figure out why it's not working as expected.